# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewcommitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyleforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {


if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects ]count]>0)

        {
            NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
            [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
            //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];




    }
}
```

Comment: What says `NSLog(@"ManagedObject: %@",managedObject)`?

Comment: it will show  values stored values and also showing the relationship between them.When i double tapp in table view entry then it will crash ...

Comment: next time when i double click on delete button  managed object context is nil. managed object context at delete->>>>>>>(null)
2014-06-25 13:11:48.864 WindowNation[3848:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument'

Comment: 2   CoreData                            0x005388ff -[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:] + 367
 3   WindowNation                        0x0003a6a2 -[HomeOwnerInfoListingVC tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 418
 4   UIKit                               0x009312b3 -                      0x01f1e30e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
 20  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1db33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
 21  CoreFoundation                      0x01f1d94b C

Comment: Well, my guess is: At first, it's there, but after you delete it, you don't seems to change `self.fetchedResultsController` which may have a `nil` value. Try to understand why at first its non-nil, and why after it's nil.

Comment: At view will appear  i have nil the fetch controller.